# Making HTTP requests isn’t working in React Native iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, http

I am working on a group project where we have created a React Native app. Two of my team members worked on the server-side of the project and I am working on the client-side, the app works perfectly on Android but the http requests aren't working in iOS. I tried searching for solutions, most of them said that I need to add a few lines to the info.plist file, I tried all that but none of that worked so hopefully no one will mark this question as a duplicate.

I am stuck in the Login page of the app, here is the code: 
**UserLogin.js**

```
// This function is called when the login button is pressed
submit=() => {
// Some validations

if(Object.keys(this.state.success).length==0){
  const URL="http://10.0.2.2:4000/userLogin"
  const loginconfirm = async () => {
    try {
      return await axios.post(URL,this.state)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
      }
    }
    const getloginconfirm = async () => {
    const confirm = await loginconfirm()

     if (confirm.data.message=="success") {
        alert("Successfully logged in")
        UserInfo.setName(confirm.data.name);
        UserInfo.setId(confirm.data.id);  
        if(confirm.data.category=="Exporter"){
          const {navigation} = this.props;
          navigation.navigate('ScreenMove')
          //Should go to ScreenMove.js
        }else{
          const {navigation} = this.props;
          navigation.navigate('FarmerHomePage')
        }
       }
    else{alert("The username does not exist or password does not match the username")}
     }
    getloginconfirm();
}
```

Here's my info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>UNAGI</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict/>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

> 2020-04-29 20:02:04.589406+0530 UNAGI[30263:604617] []
>   nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C8:2] Socket SO_ERROR [60: Operation
>   timed out] 2020-04-29 20:02:04.590542+0530 UNAGI[30263:604617]
>   Connection 8: received failure notification 2020-04-29
>   20:02:04.592849+0530 UNAGI[30263:604617] Connection 8: failed to
>   connect 1:60, reason -1 2020-04-29 20:02:04.594920+0530
>   UNAGI[30263:604617] Connection 8: encountered error(1:60) 2020-04-29
>   20:02:04.605649+0530 UNAGI[30263:604617] Task
>   <695EDB52-BC43-4A20-93D2-A3481D44468C>.<3> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes
>   (error code: -1001 [1:60]) 2020-04-29 20:02:04.622585+0530
>   UNAGI[30263:604513] Task <695EDB52-BC43-4A20-93D2-A3481D44468C>.<3>
>   finished with error [-1001] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001
>   "The request timed out." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=60,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x60000235c360 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork
>   Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=60,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <695EDB52-BC43-4A20-93D2-A3481D44468C>.<3>,
>   _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
>       "LocalDataTask <695EDB52-BC43-4A20-93D2-A3481D44468C>.<3>" ), NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://10.0.2.2:4000/userLogin,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://10.0.2.2:4000/userLogin,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1} 2020-04-29 20:02:04.639 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Error: timeout of 0ms
>   exceeded 2020-04-29 20:02:04.761
>   [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Possible Unhandled Promise
>   Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'confirm.data')
>   getloginconfirm$@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:132789:32
>   tryCatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:30544:23
>   invoke@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:30720:32
>   tryCatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:30544:23
>   invoke@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:30620:30
>   http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:30630:21
>   tryCallOne@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:3344:16
>   http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:3445:27
>   _callTimer@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:32458:17
>   _callImmediatesPass@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:32494:19
>   callImmediates@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:32712:33
>   callImmediates@[native code]
>   __callImmediates@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2752:35
>   http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2538:34
>   __guard@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2735:15
>   flushedQueue@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:2537:21
>   flushedQueue@[native code] callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@[native
>   code]

Appreciate the feedback! :)

Comment: Are you still having this issue? Or how did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @BaderSerhan I didn’t find any solution for this :/

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I appreciate it.